# How to add a link rel code in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7

I am a new developer and I want to implement a popup screen in Drupal 7.
I found a code online and it works, except for the "link rel" code the example has at the `<head>` section.

The code is the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/colorbox.css" />
```

I tried opening this link and adding the whole code at the styles.css file, but the popup appears without any style.

Is there a way to do it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you added the CSS content to your CSS file maybe you should clear the CSS cache to see changes.
You also should check the selectors match to the CSS rules (for instance with Firebug in Firefox browser).
Or in the template.php you can add external CSS in this way:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
    `drupal_add_css('http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/colorbox.css',`    
    `array('type' => 'external'));`
}
```

Comment: maybe it is the cache problem, because I used this code and it didn't work! I'll try it again though!

Comment: by CSS cache you mean clearing all caches from administrator->performance, right?

Comment: As far as I know for external CSS Drupal does not use internal cache only for internal CSS files.
You can clear CSS cache with admin menu Flush all caches/Css and Javascript (or with drush: drush cc css-js).